# merge two adapters to show one from each in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I have two adapters and i want to merge them together in one ListView .so i can display one from each.
Example

```
Adapter1 , Adapter2.

ListView 
getView(position = 0) -> from Adapter1
getView(position = 1) -> from Adapter2
getView(position = 2) -> from Adapter1
getView(position = 3) -> from Adapter2
getView(position = 4) -> from Adapter1
```

i saw  Merge Adapter by Commonsware  it displays the items in the same order you add adapters to it . example : mergeadapter.addAdapter(adapter1);mergeadapter.addAdapter(adapter2); then it will display all adapter1 items then all adapter2 items , there is no way to display on from each like in the example i wrote .

Comment: You shouldn't use two different *adapters* for this. You should use one adapter, with the data source of both combined.

Comment: @RGraham Sometimes you just have two adapters coming to you so you can not combine the data

Comment: @Alex True, but `adapter.getItem(position)` should allow you to populate a new source from the existing adapters. From a code standpoint, I would argue that a merging of `Adapter1` and `Adapter2` is no longer one or the other, but is now `Adapter3`. Of course maybe there's a scenario I haven't thought of

Comment: @RGraham. Yes, I didn't realize there's more to the requirements in question.

Answer (score 1):

There's a great component to do that and more (you can merge adapters and single views, too)

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge

Comment: i saw this it display the items in the same order you add adapters to it . example : mergeadapter.addAdapter(adapter1);mergeadapter.addAdapter(adapter2);
then it will display all adapter1 items then all adapter2 items , there is no way to display on from each like in the example i wrote in the original question

Answer (score 0):

You should use data *source* for each adapter to populate a third, main adapter. Here is a very rudimentary String` example:

```
String[] dataSource1 = { "One", "Three" };
String[] dataSource2 = { "Two", "Four"};
String[] dataSource3 = new String[4];
int index = 0;
for(int i=0; i< dataSource1.length; i++) {
    dataSource3[index++] = dataSource1[i];
    dataSource3[index++] = dataSource2[i];
}
// dataSource3 == { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four" }
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.itemlayout, dataSource3);
```

Like I said, it's very basic and doesn't scale at all, but it illustrates what you need to do.